# retrieving data from three tables using MySQL

Tags: mysql

i am having three tables namely

1)cd_register

```
|----------------------------------------------------|
|   username  |  name   |  age   | sex   | dob       |
|----------------------------------------------------|
```

2)cd_social

```
|-------------------------------------|
|   username  |  religion  |  caste   |
|-------------------------------------|
```

and
3)cd_professional

```
|----------------------------------------|
|   username  | occupation | education   |
|----------------------------------------|
```

now i'm using this query in mysql but its giving error

```
SELECT cd_register.name, cd_register.age, cd_register.dob, cd_social.religion, cd_social.caste, cd_professional.profession
FROM cd_register, cd_social,cd_professional
WHERE 
cd_register.sex = 'Male',
cd_social.religion = 'Hindu',
cd_social.caste = 'Brahmin',
cd_professional.occupation = 'Doctor',
cd_register.username = cd_social.username AND
cd_register.username = cd_professional.username
```

now i want to mention that `username` is the `primary key` of all the tables. Also
`username` of `cd_register` is `foreign key` in `cd_social`. Also
`username` of `cd_register` is `foreign key` in `cd_professional`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `join`

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.age, t1.dob, t2.religion, t2.caste, t3.profession
FROM cd_register as t1
LEFT JOIN cd_social as t2 
ON t1.username = t2.username and t2.caste = 'Brahmin' and t2.religion ='Hindu'
LEFT JOIN cd_professional as t3 
ON t1.username = t3.username and t3.occupation = 'Doctor' 
WHERE t1.sex = 'Male'
```

Comment: @ sararov..its absolutely perfect my friend...just one thing u used cd_professional.profession.. Anyways i corrected it

Answer (score 1):

You have commas in your `WHERE` clause, which will definitely cause an error (you probably want `AND`s there)  Try this:

```
SELECT cdr.name, cdr.age, cdr.dob, cds.religion, cds.caste, cdp.profession
FROM cd_register       cdr
JOIN cd_social         cds
  ON cdr.username    = cds.username
JOIN cd_professional   cdp
  ON cdr.username    = cdp.username
WHERE cdr.sex        = 'Male'
  AND cds.religion   = 'Hindu'
  AND cds.caste      = 'Brahmin'
  AND cdp.occupation = 'Doctor'
```

Comment: its giving some error my frnd..You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM candidate_register_table cdr  JOIN candidate_social_table cds  ON cdr.usern' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

It might help to tell us what the error is.

Also, the last two lines are identical.

You probably need to join the cd_professional table, too.